# Convert particle system to animated meshes Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes, conversion, system

We know the code below works in 2.79. But trying it in 2.8x it will not take effect and no error will be displayed. Anyone knows how what could be missing there?

```
import bpy

# Set these to False if you don't want to key that property.
KEYFRAME_LOCATION = True
KEYFRAME_ROTATION = True
KEYFRAME_SCALE = True
KEYFRAME_VISIBILITY = True  # Viewport and render visibility.

def create_objects_for_particles(ps, obj):
    # Duplicate the given object for every particle and return the duplicates.
    # Use instances instead of full copies.
    obj_list = []
    mesh = obj.data
    for i, _ in enumerate(ps.particles):
        dupli = bpy.data.objects.new(
                    name="particle.{:03d}".format(i),
                    object_data=mesh)
        bpy.context.scene.objects.link(dupli)
        obj_list.append(dupli)
    return obj_list

def match_and_keyframe_objects(ps, obj_list, start_frame, end_frame):
    # Match and keyframe the objects to the particles for every frame in the
    # given range.
    for frame in range(start_frame, end_frame + 1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        for p, obj in zip(ps.particles, obj_list):
            match_object_to_particle(p, obj)
            keyframe_obj(obj)

def match_object_to_particle(p, obj):
    # Match the location, rotation, scale and visibility of the object to
    # the particle.
    loc = p.location
    rot = p.rotation
    size = p.size
    if p.alive_state == 'ALIVE':
        vis = True
    else:
        vis = False
    obj.location = loc
    # Set rotation mode to quaternion to match particle rotation.
    obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    obj.rotation_quaternion = rot
    obj.scale = (size, size, size)
    obj.hide = not(vis)
    obj.hide_render = not(vis)

def keyframe_obj(obj):
    # Keyframe location, rotation, scale and visibility if specified.
    if KEYFRAME_LOCATION:
        obj.keyframe_insert("location")
    if KEYFRAME_ROTATION:
        obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion")
    if KEYFRAME_SCALE:
        obj.keyframe_insert("scale")
    if KEYFRAME_VISIBILITY:
        obj.keyframe_insert("hide")
        obj.keyframe_insert("hide_render")

def main():
    # Assume only 2 objects are selected.
    # The active object should be the one with the particle system.
    ps_obj = bpy.context.object
    obj = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj != ps_obj][0]
    ps = ps_obj.particle_systems[0]  # Assume only 1 particle system is present.
    start_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
    end_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_end
    obj_list = create_objects_for_particles(ps, obj)
    match_and_keyframe_objects(ps, obj_list, start_frame, end_frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Few changes in 2.80:

- Objects are linked to a scene via a collection
- 'hide' has became 'hide_viewport'
- You need to get the dependency graph and an evaluated object to have access to particles

Here is the corrected code (modifications are commented '2.80: something'):

```
import bpy

# Set these to False if you don't want to key that property.
KEYFRAME_LOCATION = True
KEYFRAME_ROTATION = True
KEYFRAME_SCALE = True
KEYFRAME_VISIBILITY = True  # Viewport and render visibility.

def create_objects_for_particles(ps, obj):
    # Duplicate the given object for every particle and return the duplicates.
    # Use instances instead of full copies.
    obj_list = []
    mesh = obj.data
    for i, _ in enumerate(ps.particles):
        dupli = bpy.data.objects.new(
                    name="particle.{:03d}".format(i),
                    object_data=mesh)
        # 2.80: link to objects in collection
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(dupli)
        obj_list.append(dupli)
    return obj_list

def match_and_keyframe_objects(ps, obj_list, start_frame, end_frame):
    # Match and keyframe the objects to the particles for every frame in the
    # given range.
    for frame in range(start_frame, end_frame + 1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        for p, obj in zip(ps.particles, obj_list):
            match_object_to_particle(p, obj)
            keyframe_obj(obj)

def match_object_to_particle(p, obj):
    # Match the location, rotation, scale and visibility of the object to
    # the particle.
    loc = p.location
    rot = p.rotation
    size = p.size
    if p.alive_state == 'ALIVE':
        vis = True
    else:
        vis = False
    obj.location = loc
    # Set rotation mode to quaternion to match particle rotation.
    obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    obj.rotation_quaternion = rot
    obj.scale = (size, size, size)
    # 2.80: hide_viewport instead of hide
    obj.hide_viewport = not(vis)
    obj.hide_render = not(vis)

def keyframe_obj(obj):
    # Keyframe location, rotation, scale and visibility if specified.
    if KEYFRAME_LOCATION:
        obj.keyframe_insert("location")
    if KEYFRAME_ROTATION:
        obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion")
    if KEYFRAME_SCALE:
        obj.keyframe_insert("scale")
    if KEYFRAME_VISIBILITY:
        # 2.80: hide_viewport instead of hide
        obj.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport")
        obj.keyframe_insert("hide_render")

def main():
    # Assume only 2 objects are selected.
    # The active object should be the one with the particle system.
    ps_obj = bpy.context.object
    obj = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj != ps_obj][0]
    # 2.80: Get the dependency graph
    dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    # 2.80: Get an evaluated object from it
    eval_obj = ps_obj.evaluated_get(dg)
    ps = eval_obj.particle_systems[0]  # Assume only 1 particle system is present.
    start_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
    end_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_end
    obj_list = create_objects_for_particles(ps, obj)
    match_and_keyframe_objects(ps, obj_list, start_frame, end_frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you solution worked flawlessly on the first try! Thank you so much!!

Comment: hi @lemon thanks for this script, I'm trying to update it to work for geometry that has animated armature attached, I wonder if you could have a look at my attempt question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167452/convert-particles-to-animated-mesh-including-existing-armature-animation

Comment: @Nick, hi... will try to have a look (but not sure to have time).