# Baked particle system animation can't be exported because of enable/disable animation

Tags: python, animation, particles, export, baking

I am trying to import a particle system animation baked in Blender into the [Effect House](https://effecthouse.tiktok.com). The problem is that the [script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153515) I use animates the enable/disable of each particle (see screenshot) and when exporting to FBX, only enabled particles are exported (although I chose export selected). There is no such problem in the [video](https://youtu.be/a5w9D1cJplM?t=148) tutorial (but there the author used a script for an older version of Blender).

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong script version.

In the video is not animated visibility, so I would say **the visibility is animated by Scale** ...

[Here you can find modified version of the script :)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167633/2214)
by [@spiraloid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/75772/spiraloid)

[image]

Notes:

- works for me under 3.4
- generated objects are stored in Collection
- I wanted to offer export particles as .abc, but format is not supported by Effect House at the moment

Comment: This is super cool and exactly what I needed, thank you so much!